# Changing wallpaper using VBS on Windows 10 doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, vbscript

So I've been trying to use a vbs file to change my desktop wallpaper on Windows 10. 
The vbs file contains:

```
dim shell
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wallpaper = "C:\Users\mypc\Pictures\wallpaper.jpg"
shell.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper", wallpaper
shell.Run "%windir%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 1, True
```

The problem is it doesn't always work. It works about 1 in 10 times I execute it. The vbs doesn't throw any errors whatsoever. The weird thing is that the registry key actually changes to the correct wallpaper, but the change is not reflected in the desktop background as if they weren't associated or something was "stuck".
Any ideas on what the problem could be or how can I debug it will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of digging up I found [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Change-window-borderdesktop-609a6fb2).
It uses the PowerShell to work. It can change wallpapers and other stuff related to destktop customization too and it always works (at least the wallpaper change part). 
In case anyone is interested this is how you do it: Execute the following to change the wallpaper

```
PS> Set-OSCWallpaper [wallpaper path] Stretch
```

Note that you probably need to enable remote sign for PowerShell scripts. You can achieve this by opening the PowerShell as administrator and executing:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to trigger the event where Windows checks the registry key to see what wallpaper it should display, since it won't be checking the registry all the time.

There's probably a few ways to do this, but I'd bet that doing something like changing the wallpaper properties to "tiled" and then back to what it was before would probably do it.

Comment: How does the author do that specifically?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it but I think the wallpaper properties also live in the registry so would that really work? unless there's another way to change the property.

Comment: @gabyarg25 - Saying "it possible" without any specifics isn't actually that not helpful.  Since it does not appear you know how to implement what you are trying to suggest, I have to issue a downvote, if at some point the necessary details are provided I will reverse my vote.

Comment: Just use the `Set-OSCWallpaper` command in Powershell.